# Nested loops for Paste function

Tags: r

I wish to use nested loops to produce 125 labels for 25 manifest variables & 5 latent variables
as_1_1 to as_25_1 ... as_1_5 to as_25_5
I can't seem to get the code working.
I have tried this:

```
for (i in 1:25) for (j in 1:5) 
  {
    AsLabs1  <- paste("as",1:i,1:j,sep="_")
  }


AsLabs1

"as_1_1"  "as_2_2"  "as_3_3"  "as_4_4"  "as_5_5"  "as_6_1"  "as_7_2"  
"as_8_3"  "as_9_4"  "as_10_5" "as_11_1" "as_12_2" "as_13_3" "as_14_4" 
"as_15_5" "as_16_1" "as_17_2" "as_18_3" "as_19_4" "as_20_5" "as_21_1" 
"as_22_2" "as_23_3" "as_24_4" "as_25_5"
```

but I need the loop to be output all 25 variables for each value of j (1 to 5), not just 5.
I realize the solution must be quite simple what i am doing wrong.

Comment: No loop necessary: `do.call(paste, c(list("as", sep = "_"), expand.grid(1:25, 1:5)))`

Comment: You are rewiting your variable `AsLabs1` every time you execute the loop. It serves no purpose.

Comment: @Roland Souldn't you answer the question? I have tested both your code and the one by @AndersEllernBilgrau and `identical(AsLabs1, AsLabs2)` returns `TRUE`.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
paste("as", apply(expand.grid(1:25, 1:5), 1, paste, collapse = "_"), sep = "_")
```

Your own code works with slight modification:

```
AsLabs1 <- character()
for (i in 1:25) {
  for (j in 1:5) {
    AsLabs1  <- append(AsLabs1, paste("as", i, j, sep = "_"))
  }
}
```

*Edit* Corrected mistake in nested loop.

Comment: @griffinevo Saving the first line as `AsLabs2`, and running `length(setdiff(AsLabs1, AsLabs2))==0` returns `TRUE`. So it does work, unless you have requirement on the orders.

Comment: when I run it I get a vector of length 1625

Comment: @griffinevo Arh yes, sorry, it was still `1:i` and `1:j` and not `i` and `j` inside `paste` in my post. So it was different from my local session. Should now be corrected. So now, `all(sort(AsLabs1) == sort(AsLabs2))` indeed is `TRUE`. Sorry for my confusion.

Answer (score 2):

I personally **wouldn't bother with a nested loop**, just use `paste` with a "_" `sep`, and `rep` function with `times` and `each` arguments specified.

```
AsLabs <- paste(rep("as", times = 25*5), rep (1:25, times = 5), 
  rep(1:5, each = 25), sep = "_")
```

... *If* you are determined to **use a nested loop**, it can be done with a slight modification to your code, adding the `rep` function:

```
AsLabs1 <- rep(NA, 125)
for (i in 1:25) for (j in 1:5) 
  {
    AsLabs1  <- paste("as",rep(1:i, each = 5),1:j,sep="_")
  }
```

I **wouldn't use a nested loop because** *i*) it's unnecessarily **complex** code and *ii*) considerably **slower**  to run (my paste approach is about 40 times faster than the nested loop solution [and about 7 times faster than the apply method in the answer from Anders])

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `outer` for this,

```
paste0('as_', outer(1:25, 1:5, paste, sep = '_'))
```